# How to update Akita state 'ui' property

Tags: angular-akita, akita

I have an Akita state interface set up with a related store, as shown below...

```
export interface GdTaskState extends EntityState<GdTask, number> {
  dataPage: {
    tasksLoaded: boolean;
    pageNumber: number;
    pageSize: number;
    totalTasks: number;
  };
  ui: {
    view: TaskView;
    folderFilter: FolderFilter;
    filter: TaskFilter;
    tableRows: number;
    heightSet: boolean;
    tableHeight: number;
    tableWidth: number;
  };
}
```

I am trying to set up a store method to update just the 'tableHeight' property, without affecting any of the existing 'UI' properties/  How do I do this?

The Akita docs show this as the format...

[image]

... but this seems to zap all the other properties at the 'ui' level

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly -

In the service file, call the update method of the store and then update it using the spread operator to retain all other values except the one being updated.
For example,

```
changeTableHeight(value) {
   this.todosStore.update((todoState) => ({
        ui: { ...todoState.ui, tableHeight: value }
    }));
}
```